# Azure data factory - Data Flow-how to get duration for a data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory, dataflow

In the **output** of **Copy Data**, there is a **"copyDuration"**.

Is there also a duration part in the output of the **data flow**, which is the amount time spent executing this whole data flow? How can I get the **total seconds** of this data flow activity?

Is this the right way? (@activity('activityName').Duration)

If it' s the right way, how can I transform this duration(hh:mm:ss) (like "00:01:02") to total seconds("62")?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transform hh:mm:ss to total seconds in azure data factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185485/how-to-transform-hhmmss-to-total-seconds-in-azure-data-factory)

Answer (score 0):

Yes `@activity('activityName').Duration` will give you duration details of your data flow execution.

Regarding, transforming duration to seconds. Kindly check below link.
[How to transform hh:mm:ss to total seconds in azure data factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185485/how-to-transform-hhmmss-to-total-seconds-in-azure-data-factory)